# Do I need an image burning software in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, burning, iso-image

I've always used Nero in previous Windows versions. Do I still need it (or some other program) in Windows 7, or is the built-in burning software (whatever it might be) good enough?

Answer (score 3):

No

But personally I recommend [IMGburn](http://www.imgburn.com/)

Comment: I did not get that from that thread. Having burned a Linux ISO to CD just last night on Windows 7, I would dispute that statement.

Comment: I've misread the question! Edited the question

Comment: +1 for ImgBurn.  It's simple, well-written, and has a decent feature set for dealing with disk images.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 7 , we can do almost every thing we commonly doing in nero.
But it lacks virtual device mounting feature.Expecting that feature in coming service pack.

Comment: Quite controversial feature in the gaming sector, they wouldn't put such a thing without having pressure from lot of big firms. Plenty of games protections are scanning and refusing to launch if such a virtual device is detected. So I don't really see Microsoft putting that as a pre-installed feature.

Comment: @Gnoupi You Are right.Its just a hope.

Answer (score 0):

Given that I had bad experience in the past with the burning engines in Windows, I recommend using Nero. Nero includes an explicit complete verification of everything that has been burned to confirm that your data indeed was properly burned. This is also a reason why I use it under Linux as well.

Although Nero costs some money, if you use it for backups or important data, the cost of the software is well covered by the value of the data you may burn.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Nero Essentials](http://www.nero.com/eng/downloads-nero9-free.php) / [Infra Recorder](http://infrarecorder.org/?page_id=5) for Win7...Both ot them are free...